# gnuplot set y2axis range from colum

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

I have the following data file:

```
# Throughput(op/sec)  Num_tr   Bytes_sent(sec)
     3000               10        12000  
      ...               ...         ...
```

Where throughput is the number of operation per second a client is able to do, Num_tr is the number of threads, and bytes_sent is the number of bytes sent per second.

Now, I am able to plot the thread vs. Throughput graph, getting for example 10 on my x axis and 3000 on my y axis. However, since Bytes_sent and Throughput strictly correlates, I wanted to also use the `y2axis` command to show the bytes sent in the same plot. The ticks position should be the same, but the value of the y2tics should correspond to ($3 / $1) * the y2tick value defined in the range (1000, 2000, 3000)

```
set yrange [0:18000]
set ytics nomirror
set y2label 'Throughput (op/sec)'
set y2tics 5 
set y2label 'Bytes_sent'
set y2range [0:18000 *($3 / $1)]  <---------------- 
plot "data.dat" index 0 using 2:1:xtic(2) ...
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices

(1) You can link y2 to y1 using the "set link" command and providing the equations relating bytes sent and throughput

```
total_time = <you know this, I take it?>
throughput(bytes_sent) = bytes_sent / total_time
bytes(throughput) = throughput * total_time    
set link y2 via throughput(y) inverse bytes(y)
set ytics 5 nomirror
set y2tics nomirror   # range will exactly track y1
plot "data.dat" index 0 using 2:1
```

I don't know what you intended with "xtics(1)" but it cannot be correct since column 1 is being used for y values, not x values.

(2) You can plot them independently

```
plot "data.dat" index 0 using 2:1 axes x1y1, \
     "data.dat" index 0 using 2:(thoughput($1)) axes x1y2
```

In this case you do not need to link the axes or set the ranges explicitly. The plot will have two lines, but if the correlation is perfect they will superimpose.

Comment: I didn't understand (1), I know total time  but it shouldn't be relevant for this plot. Looking at the data I see that each bytes_sent / throughput in each row produces a slightly different value, so it is not a constant value I can simply multiply with the throughput. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: "total time" may be the wrong description.  Whatever time interval it is that you are using to generate the throughput values.   I.e., whatever time interval makes the pair of equations throughput(bytes) and bytes(througput) correct for your data.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you!